# how to return my own observable depending on multiple subscribe of data

Tags: angular

Struggled for hours and hours..... How can I return an custom observable which depends on multiple chained subscribe on other observables. Like, I call a function and subscribe and check the value of the observable, then decide which other function to call. Then call another http request to get a new observable from the request. Finally, return my custom observable depending on the previous observable.

Comment: A good rule of thumb when using observables is that you should only have 1 subscribe at the consumer side, nesting subscribes usually is an anti-pattern that you can get around by using the right operators. You can also create your own subject and emit values to it asynchronously. Without seeing your code I can't really tell you what to do

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@danielt1263/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f there are multiple ways to do that

```
this.homeworld = this.http.get('/api/people/1').pipe(
 mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld)));
```

here's simple example how one observable depends on another,giving exact answer on your question is still a problem, so you can just search around mergeMap.

Answer (score 0):

use switchMap operator

```
import {switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";
import of as off from "rxjs";
      processData().pipe(switchMap(result)=>{
       if(result=="first"){
         return this.httpService.get("/api/first");
       }
       return this.httpService.get("/api/second");
    }).pipe(switchMap(response)=>{
       if(response==true){
       return off("success");  
    }
     return off("fail");
    })
```